# Replace very long HTML text in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find and replace very long HTML text in a SQL Server temp table (I'm using SQL Server 2012).

The query structure is:

```
UPDATE #Descriptions
SET Desc1 = replace(Desc1, 'VERY LONG HTML 1','VERY LONG HTML 2')
WHERE Desc1 like 'VERY LONG HTML 1'
```

I'm getting

> Text or binary data will be truncated

error. The HTML parts are long, but should fit easily - whole thing fits in `varchar(max)` and these are only parts of it.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you!
M.

Comment: what is the length of Desc1 column datatype

Comment: My guess is that the second parameter exceeds 8,000 characters? This is very poorly documented but the second parameter to replace is varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000). With the implicit cast you will get the error message you mentioned.

Comment: if the datatype is XML or not will drive your solution.  to emphasize Sean above I would only do this by casting to a varchar4000 first and know for sure that the field never goes past 4000 characters.   Also I would PreCheck by doing a CHARINDEX call. once again if less than 4000 characters.   If this is a one off one time thing you may want to try a program or special SSIS package.    The SQL XML UPDATE stuff may work better for you if you have a known element in the SQL.

Comment: Thanks guys! Indeed it exceeds 8000 chars. Maybe I'll try to cut the string in few parts and do it again..

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
  field = replace(cast(field as varchar(max)),'string' ,'replacement')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This string must be too long I guess, because it did not work either. Will have find some other way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

As [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) pointed out it's because of output string being truncated. This can be found in official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> **Return Types**
>
> Returns nvarchar if one of the input arguments is of the nvarchar data type; otherwise, REPLACE returns varchar. Returns
> NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL. If string_expression is not
> of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLACE truncates the return
> value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes,
> string_expression must be explicitly cast to a large-value data type.

This can be workarounded by splitting your string into multiple string of fixed length, replacing data in there and then concatenating them back together.