# Insufficient memory when opening TClientDataSet with a REPLACE in the underlying query

Tags: sql-server, delphi, out-of-memory, firedac, tclientdataset

My Delphi code opens a `TFDQuery` (FireDAC), then opens the `TClientDataSet` connected to it via a `TDataSetProvider`:

```
ClientDataSetData.Close;
with QueryData do
begin
  Close;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add(ASelectSQL);
  Open;
end;    
ClientDataSetData.Open;
```

`ASelectSQL` contains this SQL:

```
SELECT TT_NIV_ID,
TT_NIV,
REPLACE(TT_NIV_NAME, '|', '!') as TT_NIV_NAME2
FROM TT_SYS_PRJ_NIV
```

The `ClientDataSetData.Open` gives an insufficient memory error on a dataset with 42200 records.

If I inspect the result data (in the Delphi code) I see that `TT_NIV_NAME2` is a string of length 8000!
From the [REPLACE() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max),
>   REPLACE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes

... so this seems to be happening; not just truncating but also setting the result type.

`TT_NIV_NAME` is a `VARCHAR(50)`, so a quick fix is to change the SQL to

```
SELECT TT_NIV_ID,
TT_NIV,
CAST(REPLACE(TT_NIV_NAME, '|', '!') as VARCHAR(50))  as TT_NIV_NAME2
FROM TT_SYS_PRJ_NIV
```

but this is with user defined SQL that I have no control over. Next time (s)he may run a with a `REPLACE` on something else... I'd prefer a generic solution.

**Is there anything I can do to the Delphi code** (`TClientDataset` or `TFDQuery` or `TFDConnection` settings?) that prevents this high memory usage?

<strike>And frankly, why would `REPLACE` conclude that "string_expression is not of type varchar(max)", when `TT_NIV_NAME` is a `VARCHAR(50)`?</strike>

Notes:

- Tested with several SQL server drivers - it's not a driver issue.
- The `TFDConnection` has `FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll` and `FetchOptions.Items := FetchOptions.Items - [fiMeta]`;
  `fmAll` must stay<sup>*</sup>, and not subtracting `fiMeta` makes no difference.
- Related [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952766/replace-very-long-html-text-in-sql-server-database) but here `string_expression` is longer than 8000, or [[2]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160744/the-result-of-replace-and-convert-is-a-varchar8000-how-can-i-have-a-varchar?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) where `string_expression` is not of type `varchar(max)` but both do not apply to my SQL data.
- Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 using FireDAC against SQL Server 2012, Win32 app running under Win7 or Win10

<sup>* .. to prevent the famous hstmt error in an environment where only very basic SQL Server drivers are installed; and not setting it makes no difference anyway in my test app.</sup>

Comment: The REPLACE() does make the result varchar(8000) which isn't the real problem. The problem is FireDAC using fixed storage for this and consuming excessive memory.

Comment: @Brian, but what else can FireDAC do? The driver describes the field as such. Anywya, what makes you feel that FireDAC allocates memory as such?

Comment: @Victoria FireDAC could store a reference/pointer to a variable length string in the fixed length buffer. The poster is getting out of memory errors and past experience with wide varchar() fields and Delphi database connection components where this was the problem makes me think it may be the case here as well.

Comment: @Brian, FireDAC's storage is efficiently written. In this case the field is described and treated as BLOB (and as such allocates only as much as is fetched from DBMS). Blame MIDAS here (client dataset). My advice is, get rid of MIDAS. Forever. Besides, the OP says, _"The ClientDataSetData.Open gives an insufficient memory error"_. If it was FireDAC's issue, the exception would be raised at their query object opening.

Comment: @Victoria I concede - my statement about it being FireDAC storing the varchar(8000) inefficiently is not correct.

Comment: @Brian, no worries :) Here it's MIDAS who eats that much. How to stop it is difficult to say for me. I would print MIDAS source code to paper and send it to the deep space (as a possible alien invasion prevention). The source code on all computers I'd delete. But I see that the OP is modifying some legacy application and that it might be difficult to lose it. In any case, FireDAC describes the field correctly here and uses memory only as much as is fetched. And preventing users from writing e.g. `SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000));` is merely impossible.

Comment: @nil I was assuming that varchar(max) means any max sized varchar, i.e. varchar(n), but [that is not the case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

We have 'solved' this by applying a mapping rule specifically for this 8000 character ANSIstring. I know, it's dirty, but for the legacy app it works (especially since we were using [SQLDirect](http://www.sqldirect-soft.com/) before switching to FireDAC, and there varchars > 256 bytes were translated to memo already).

```
with FDConnection.FormatOptions.MapRules.Add do
begin
  SourceDataType := dtAnsiString;
  SizeMin := 8000;
  SizeMax := 8000;
  TargetDataType := dtMemo;
end;
```

This mapping is specific to SQL Server, because the REPLACE function in the other two database types we support (Oracle, FireBird) does not have the SQL Server behavior.